# Addon/ Plugins are not applicable in IE ActiveX control PB

Tags: internet-explorer, controls, activex, powerbuilder

We have powerbuilder application where we are using Webbrowser Internet Explorer inside of application using IE ActiveX control. As per documentation it will inherit all settings from default internet explorer of the system where application is running.

However we are facing issue where plugins are used in our web-page. In that case, Browser inside powerbuilder application is not able to utilize addons/plugins which has been enabled in Internet explorer of the respective system.

Any help on this issue would be very helpful.

In case if current code required then I would update question accordingly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the bitness of your app? Which IE security zones do your web sites map to in the real IE.

Comment: We are using 32 bit application. Internet >> Medium security zones.

Comment: Hi, Please post back with the names and clisid's of the Controls you want to run. (Tools>Manage Addons).

Comment: 1. Name: Installer for OpenTok Plugin, Class Id: {6C2249D6-A0EB-5438-90F8-E90E848C5368} 2. Name: Media Plugin, Class Id: {D9B59700-C71C-549C-9205-B5B15F3901EC}

Comment: I could not find the vendors of those controls. with a web search of their CLSID's...If you can find their web sites they may be able to suggest and upgrade path to continue to use their products. The markup page that powerbuilder WBC app hosts has to be modified... tut that may not work either... workaround provided.

Answer (score 0):

You should seek programming help for your powerbuilder application that uses the WBC..... Using the powerbuilder IDE or a Resource Editor you have to make changes to the markup of the web page (resource).... Search your source for instances of the object to locate where all the ActiveX plugins are used...

Basically where you have object tags like (I am using the CLID of Macromedia flash here just as an example)

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" 
        codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0"
        width="590" height="90" 
        id="mymoviename">
    <param name="movie" value="media/Car-speakers-590x90.swf" />
    <img alt="out of date macromedia flash is disabled/blocked"/>
</object>
```

must be changed to use the modern(interoperable) syntax.

```
<object id="genericflash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="media/Car-speakers-590x90.swf"
            width="590" height="90" >
        <embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="media/Car-speakers-590x90.swf" width="590" height="90" style="outline:red 1px solid" />
        <img alt="flash is disabled or activex filtering is enabled" />
    </object>
```

**You will need to contact the vendors of those two Active X controls to
see what they recommend you do..... either update their controls and your markup or replace their controls and your media with HTML media controls and your legacy media format with MP4 or webm.**

If they are not still in business, then you have no choice but to re-program your markup and convert it to use HMTL5 media elements, as well of the format of your media files.